# Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: mario.png

Tags: java, libgdx

Im learning libgdx and I tried to call mario.png on my screen, but it didn't work.
I even tried to set the file path like ("/assets/data/mario.png") and still didn't work.
What should I do to fix this?

```
package com.brandong.Tutorial;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationListener;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL10;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.TextureFilter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.Sprite;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.TextureRegion;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class Tutorial implements ApplicationListener {

SpriteBatch batch;
    Texture mario;
    Vector2 position;
    @Override
    public void create() {      
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        mario = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("mario.png"));
        position = new Vector2(50,50);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {

    }

    @Override
    public void render() {      
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);


        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(mario, position.x,position.y);
        batch.end();

    }   

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void pause() {
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
    }
}
```

and the error:

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Couldn't load file: mario.png
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:140)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.FileTextureData.prepare(FileTextureData.java:64)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.load(Texture.java:142)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:133)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:112)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture.<init>(Texture.java:104)
    at com.brandong.Tutorial.Tutorial.create(Tutorial.java:22)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:136)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:114)
Caused by: com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: File not found: mario.png (Internal)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.read(FileHandle.java:133)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.length(FileHandle.java:563)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.files.FileHandle.readBytes(FileHandle.java:218)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Pixmap.<init>(Pixmap.java:137)
    ... 8 more
```

Comment: First of all make sure your assets folder is marked as `source` folder. If it is the assets folder of your android project i think it is allready set as `source`. Next thing: The `Gdx.files.Internal` looks INSIDE every source folder. This means if inside your assets there is a folder named `data` you have to say "data/mario.png", not "assets/data/mario.png". Also take care about the case (case sensitive) and the extension (.png, .jpg...)

Comment: I have the same error, but have made sure to define my path properly:
'texture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/lstex.png"));' and it is in the android projects asset folder, I have also cleaned my project, but I still get the same error

Answer (score 0):

Well if your file is in ("/assets/data/mario.png") change the following line

```
mario = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("mario.png"));
```

to

```
 mario = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("data/mario.png"));
```